# Is that possible to import a local package inside ~/go/src/ from a module?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am using go module, the file structure is like this:

```
~/some_path/goapp/go.mod
~/some_path/goapp/go.sum
~/some_path/goapp/main.go

~/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo/foo.go
```

Inside `main.go`, I tried to do

```golang
import fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo
```

But, it doesn't work at all. 
I tried to add the following to go.mod:

```
require fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo
```

OR

```
require fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo
replace fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo /home/user/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo
```

None of them works. How can I achieve this?

### Edited

This question is about how to import a **local** package **inside ~/go/src/** from a module which is **outside ~/go/src/**.

In other words, the module which is outside ~/go/src/ will import a local package inside ~/go/src/. I thought I could import it directly (that is what I did in the old days without module), but I was wrong. It turns out that I have to make the local package inside ~/go/src/ become a module too.

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with? Do you get the wrong behaviour? Or an error? if so, what does it say? The `replace` directive should work (I use it frequently), but your `require` directive is missing a version though (add e.g. `latest` at the end), so perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: The replace directive refers to a path that doesn't exist (the go/src segments are missing).

Comment: @MartinTournoij I got many weird problems. I have added latest, but it doesn't work either. I am using vscode. In the beginning, it complains "no file parsed...." in vscode. And then after adding require and replace, the vscode just failed parse the main.go at all. It complains "No symbols found in document main.go". If I try to run `go build`, it will complain `invalid module version "latest": malformed module path:` and `replace module/path [v1.2.3] => ../local/directory`.

Comment: @Peter I just typed the question by hand. My actual env uses the correct path because I always use `pwd` to copy & paste path. Please refer to the previous comment for more details. Thanks.

Comment: Your `replace` line is not formatted correctly, it should contain `=>`. Instead of editing `go.mod` by hand you can use `go mod edit -replace fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo=/home/user/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo` and the correct line will be added.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I made it work. (1) latest doesn't work. It has to be v0.0.0. and (2) I also need to create go.mod inside the foo package. (3) `=>` is also missing for replace. So many problems. Thank you very much for your help. The version part is correct.

Comment: @DaveC you are right. I missed `=>`. Actually, there were three problems. (1) I have to provide a version v0.0.0. and (2) I also need to create go.mod inside the foo package. (3) `=>` is missing as you suggested. So many problems. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank @MartinTournoij, @Peter, @DaveC very much for their help and comments *which I have upvoted*. After following all the directions, I finally make it work.

*(Btw, I really shouldn't trust VSCode error message too much. Because I normally check errors from VSCode. Thus I didn't try `go build` before asking this question. I thought they should return the same error, but they are not. `go build` provides more reasonable error messages than VSCode.)*

There were three problems.

- Missing version from `require` in go.mod
- Missing `=>` from `replace` in go.mod
- Missing `go.mod` for `foo` package.

So to make it work:

File Structure:

```
~/some_path/goapp/go.mod
~/some_path/goapp/go.sum
~/some_path/goapp/main.go

~/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo/foo.go
~/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo/go.mod
```

~/some_path/goapp/go.mod:

```golang
...
require fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo v0.0.0
replace fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo => /home/user/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo
```

main.go:

```
package main
import fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo
...
```

~/go/src/fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo/go.mod:

```golang
module fakedomain.com/fakeuser/foo

go 1.12
```

Comment: Is Vscode using modules at all? If you’re in ~go/src it’s going to default to GOPATH

Comment: @JimB I don't quite understand your question, VScode uses modules because ~/go/src is just a third party package that I want to import and the actual project I am coding is at ~/some_path/goapp/go.mod.

Comment: Got it, that’s what I was confirming, since it would also explain the different errors. They also may have come from fmt or vet depending on what’s run first.

Answer (score -1):

I'll clearly explain how to use `go.mod` now, follow this and you should be able to get it working.

This is my directory setup (modify using yours accordingly):
`my_name/git/Project`

As you start a project in ..../Project, do `go mod init /whatever-directory-youre-in/Project`. This will add `go.mod` and `go.sum` in the same directory.

Now every import can be of the form,
`import /whatever-directory-youre-in/Project/whatever-package`

That must do!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understand how to use module alone. I also provided an answer by myself yesterday which you probably saw. My question is not how to use go module. From the question title, my question is how to import a local package which is inside ~/go/src/. Without modules in the old days, I can simply import package directly when everything are inside ~/go/src/. But with modules, I can't. That's why I need to provide a new go.mod for packages in ~/go/src/ and `replace` in go.mod for the local path. I am not a native English speaker. hopefully, my words make sense to u. Thanks.